# Archiving multiple items

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nskeyedarchiver

I'm working on a document-based app without CoreData. I have a class *Player*, which is a subclass of *NSObject*. The class has some variables and I have also properly implemented `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder`and `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` methods. That's how I'm archiving my data:

```
- (NSData *) dataOfType:(NSString *)aType
                  error:(NSError **)outError
{
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:players];
}
```

(players is an `NSMutableArray` holding some instances of the *Player* class). The saving works absolutely fine. What I would like to know is how I can also archive (and unarchive later) some variables, declared in the *Document.h* file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into NSFileWrapper, where you can define & implement saving  to / initializing from a file type which is a bundle (basically a folder) then you can save your document object alongside this array

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look